# Converthing datetime64[ns] into a Timestamp object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

I am reading date information from an Excel file which is stored as `datetime64[ns]`. However, I need this information stored as `Timestamp` object since the function to which I pass the date information does not properly work with `datetime64[ns]`.

Here is how I read the date information from Excel.

```
df= pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', sheet_name="data")
firstDate= pd.to_datetime(df[df["column"] == "date"]["end"], format='%Y-%m-%d')
firstDate
1   2020-11-01
Name: Value, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

However, if I manually create a date object, it is stored as Timestamp.

```
secondDate = pd.to_datetime('2020-11-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')
secondDate 
Timestamp('2020-11-01 00:00:00')
```

The function that I have is not working when using `firstDate`, but perfectly works with `secondDate`. How can either convert datetime64[ns] to Timestamp  or save the date from Excel as Timestamp object?

Comment: You're mistaken a dtype of a series with a scalar. `firstDate.iloc[0]` would give you a timestamp.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thanks! That resolved my issue. If I use ````firstDate.iloc[0]````, it is a timestamp. I did not know that!

Comment: btw, `pd.to_datetime(df.loc['date', 'end'])` would give you the timestamp as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although the comments appear to answer the question, it's worth mentioning why your second approach to manually create the `Timestamp` object worked:

```py
secondDate = pd.to_datetime('2020-11-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')
secondDate 
Timestamp('2020-11-01 00:00:00')
```

The documentation for `to_datetime` for the return type of a **scalar** is a `Timestamp` which is why the `iloc[0]` works as well.

> Returns:
> datetime
> If parsing succeeded. Return type depends on input (types in parenthesis correspond to fallback in case of unsuccessful timezone or out-of-range timestamp parsing):
> scalar: Timestamp (or datetime.datetime)

See: Pandas `to_datetime` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).